# vba: storing a long string in a variable with special characters

Tags: vba, string

i need to set a string equal to this in vba. how do i do it?

```
<svg 
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.0"
   width="958.69"
   height="592.78998"
   id="svg2275"
   sodipodi:version="0.32"
   inkscape:version="0.46"
   sodipodi:docname="Map of USA with state names.svg"
   sodipodi:docbase="C:\temp\webdesign"
   inkscape:output_extension="org.inkscape.output.svg.inkscape"
   onload='Init(evt)'> 
  <metadata 
     id="metadata2625"> 
    <rdf:RDF> 
      <cc:Work 
         rdf:about=""> 
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format> 
        <dc:type 
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /> 
      </cc:Work> 
    </rdf:RDF> 
  </metadata> 
  <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
      var SVGDocument = null;
      var SVGRoot = null;
      var SVGViewBox = null;
      var svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
      var xlinkns = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';
      var toolTip = null;
      var TrueCoords = null;
      var tipBox = null;
      var tipText = null;
      var tipTitle = null;
      var tipDesc = null;

      var lastElement = null;
      var titleText = '';
      var titleDesc = '';


      function Init(evt)
      {
         SVGDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
         SVGRoot = document.documentElement;
         TrueCoords = SVGRoot.createSVGPoint();

         toolTip = SVGDocument.getElementById('ToolTip');
         tipBox = SVGDocument.getElementById('tipbox');
         tipText = SVGDocument.getElementById('tipText');
         tipTitle = SVGDocument.getElementById('tipTitle');
         tipDesc = SVGDocument.getElementById('tipDesc');
      };


      function GetTrueCoords(evt)
      {
         // find the current zoom level and pan setting, and adjust the reported
         //    mouse position accordingly
         var newScale = SVGRoot.currentScale;
         var translation = SVGRoot.currentTranslate;
         TrueCoords.x = (evt.clientX - translation.x)/newScale;
         TrueCoords.y = (evt.clientY - translation.y)/newScale;
      };




      function ShowTooltip(evt, turnOn)
      {
        try
         {
            if (!evt || !turnOn)
            {
               toolTip.setAttributeNS(null, 'display', 'none');
            }
            else
            {
               var tipScale = 1/SVGRoot.currentScale;
               var textWidth = 0;
               var tspanWidth = 0;
               var boxHeight = 20;

               tipBox.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'scale(' + tipScale + ',' + tipScale + ')' );
               tipText.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'scale(' + tipScale + ',' + tipScale + ')' );

               var targetElement = evt.target;

               if ( lastElement != targetElement )
               {
                  var targetTitle = targetElement.getElementsByTagName('title').item(0);


                  if ( targetTitle )
                  {
                     titleText = targetTitle.firstChild.nodeValue;
                     tipTitle.firstChild.nodeValue = titleText;


                  }


                  var targetDesc = targetElement.getElementsByTagName('desc').item(0);


                  if ( targetDesc )
                  {
                     titleDesc = targetDesc.firstChild.nodeValue;
                     tipDesc.firstChild.nodeValue = titleDesc;
                  }
               }

               var xPos = TrueCoords.x + (10 * tipScale);
               var yPos = TrueCoords.y + (10 * tipScale);

               //return rectangle around object as SVGRect object
               var outline = tipText.getBBox();
               tipBox.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', Number(outline.width) + 10);
               tipBox.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', Number(outline.height) + 10);

               toolTip.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'translate(' + xPos + ',' + yPos + ')');
               toolTip.setAttributeNS(null, 'display', 'inline');
            }
         }
         catch(er){}
       };

   ]]></script> 

  <defs 
     id="defs2623"> 
    <inkscape:perspective 
       sodipodi:type="inkscape:persp3d"
       inkscape:vp_x="0 : 296.39499 : 1"
       inkscape:vp_y="0 : 1000 : 0"
       inkscape:vp_z="958.69 : 296.39499 : 1"
       inkscape:persp3d-origin="479.345 : 197.59666 : 1"
       id="perspective364" /> 
  </defs> 
  <sodipodi:namedview 
     inkscape:window-height="721"
     inkscape:window-width="1024"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     guidetolerance="10.0"
     gridtolerance="10.0"
     objecttolerance="10.0"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     id="base"
     inkscape:zoom="5.6568542"
     inkscape:cx="182.21001"
     inkscape:cy="-2.904429"
     inkscape:window-x="-4"
     inkscape:window-y="-4"
     inkscape:current-layer="Frames"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:showpageshadow="false"
     showborder="true"
     borderlayer="true" /> 
  <rect 
     width="959.62299"
     height="595.63739"
     x="-0.40383524"
     y="-1.2939188"
     id="water"
     style="fill:#9ec7f3" /> 
  <path 
     style="fill:#f7d3aa;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="M 923.03026,37.975518 C 922.57184,38.995849 921.76084,41.697403 921.76084,44.352463 C 921.76084,47.130382 919.49185,46.324054 921.76084,48.603761 C 922.79254,49.640303 925.33008,47.328371 926.83847,47.328371 C 928.64472,47.328371 928.45237,51.223763 930.22354,51.579668 C 932.37666,52.012321 934.08737,52.522241 936.14743,52.004798 C 938.36058,51.448909 939.8978,50.502312 942.49447,51.154539 C 943.89657,51.506717 946.44388,48.461872 947.14893,47.753502 C 949.30188,45.590391 946.8075,50.401063 946.7258,50.729408 C 946.0737,53.350095 949.5805,52.429926 951.38029,52.429926 C 954.13433,52.429926 955.03028,50.940072 955.61163,48.603761 C 955.78273,47.916101 952.46128,44.82413 952.22655,44.352463 C 951.88695,43.670052 955.05553,42.433288 956.45789,41.376556 C 959.00459,39.457537 958.11054,38.360573 956.88104,37.125259 C 955.02965,35.26515 952.06131,38.141523 950.95714,39.250906 C 949.94504,40.267774 946.8031,41.463423 945.45641,41.801685 C 943.67466,42.24922 941.73037,44.09862 940.37878,44.777594 C 938.61378,45.664254 936.79892,46.420756 934.87803,46.903242 C 933.25123,47.311861 930.50953,44.639791 929.80042,43.927334 C 928.30508,42.424964 926.15309,43.238719 924.7228,41.801685 C 923.48412,40.557171 928.92137,37.975518 923.03026,37.975518 z"
     id="path2688" /> 
  <path 
     style="fill:#f7d3aa;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="M 932.45066,120.20861 C 930.56646,122.10171 935.15436,115.51342 935.80065,112.9161 C 936.52536,110.00362 937.67175,108.72666 939.15063,106.74551 C 940.64215,104.74745 940.82562,100.846 940.82562,98.33109 C 940.82562,94.697237 941.40826,97.831106 942.11259,95.000584 C 942.7806,92.315942 941.7297,88.409776 943.58217,87.944477 C 946.31731,87.257463 949.87769,86.619091 953.54955,83.492046 C 957.14099,80.433488 956.23335,75.558206 959.25049,72.526837 C 962.75189,69.00893 959.2677,69.09194 960.36716,64.673369 C 961.11108,61.683657 959.77892,57.791585 960.36715,54.576053 C 960.92452,51.529335 958.08102,54.747152 955.74777,54.747152 C 952.95531,54.747152 954.38524,49.767421 952.12739,54.304389 C 950.71186,57.148825 948.18573,56.79432 945.85059,57.380865 C 944.22798,57.788431 941.05298,57.003598 939.15063,57.48143 C 936.94013,58.03666 936.27191,56.669364 933.72007,57.310332 C 930.25974,58.179495 930.66732,61.846501 929.98207,64.230607 C 929.29484,66.621592 924.71311,76.29826 926.47935,71.948243 C 928.45325,67.086805 924.8791,75.999318 926.84982,75.603312 C 929.51337,75.068093 934.29834,71.947646 937.07006,71.251447 C 938.8483,70.804793 941.9546,69.007602 943.78757,69.007602 C 946.05933,69.007602 937.01097,73.216374 935.64791,75.042351 C 933.89748,77.387265 932.85005,78.22614 930.48775,78.815618 C 927.67299,79.518007 930.51373,85.599379 927.5609,79.665878 C 926.27211,77.076125 925.69324,81.579246 924.07573,83.746077 C 922.03935,86.47405 923.3452,88.967737 920.72574,91.599545 C 917.87719,94.461523 918.61592,94.156215 918.49243,94.404355 C 916.99477,97.4138 915.70079,97.773488 915.70079,101.69687 C 915.70079,105.56604 916.81744,105.88691 916.81744,109.55032 C 916.81744,113.11165 916.61142,114.95296 918.49243,116.84284 C 920.32234,118.68138 922.63295,114.98367 924.88691,115.54981 C 926.91033,116.05805 932.04066,120.04384 935.24233,121.33052"
     id="path2715"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="csssssssssssssssssssssssssssssc" /> 
  <g 
     transform="matrix(1.0043294,0,0,1.0090644,-19.932863,-136.40509)"
     id="States"> 


    <path 
       d="M 242.96145,653.59282 L 244.83646,650.1553 L 247.02397,649.8428 L 247.33647,650.62405 L 245.30521,653.59282 L 242.96145,653.59282 z M 252.80525,649.99905 L 258.74278,652.49906 L 260.77404,652.18656 L 262.33654,648.43654 L 261.71154,645.15528 L 257.64902,644.68653 L 253.74275,646.40528 L 252.80525,649.99905 z M 282.49289,659.6866 L 286.08665,664.99912 L 288.43041,664.68662 L 289.52417,664.21787 L 290.93042,665.46787 L 294.52419,665.31162 L 295.4617,663.90537 L 292.64918,662.18661 L 290.77417,658.59284 L 288.74291,655.15533 L 283.11789,657.96784 L 282.49289,659.6866 z M 302.02423,668.28039 L 303.27423,666.40538 L 307.8055,667.34288 L 308.43051,666.87413 L 314.36803,667.49913 L 314.05553,668.74914 L 311.55552,670.15539 L 307.33675,669.84289 L 302.02423,668.28039 z M 307.1805,673.28041 L 309.05551,677.03043 L 312.02427,675.93667 L 312.33677,674.37416 L 310.77427,672.3429 L 307.1805,672.0304 L 307.1805,673.28041 z M 313.89928,672.18665 L 316.08679,669.37414 L 320.61806,671.7179 L 324.83683,672.81166 L 329.0556,675.46792 L 329.0556,677.34293 L 325.61809,679.06169 L 320.93056,679.99919 L 318.5868,678.59293 L 313.89928,672.18665 z M 329.99311,687.18672 L 331.55561,685.93672 L 334.83688,687.49923 L 342.18066,690.93674 L 345.46193,692.968 L 347.02443,695.31176 L 348.89944,699.53053 L 352.80571,702.03054 L 352.49321,703.28055 L 348.74319,706.40556 L 344.68067,707.81182 L 343.27442,707.18682 L 340.30565,708.90557 L 337.96189,712.03059 L 335.77438,714.8431 L 334.05562,714.68685 L 330.61811,712.18684 L 330.30561,707.81182 L 330.93061,705.46806 L 329.3681,699.99928 L 327.33684,698.28052 L 327.18059,695.78051 L 329.3681,694.84301 L 331.39936,691.87425 L 331.86811,690.93674 L 330.30561,689.21798 L 329.99311,687.18672 z"
       id="HI"
       style="fill:#ffffd0"  onmousemove=' GetTrueCoords(evt); ShowTooltip(evt, true)' onmouseout='ShowTooltip(evt, false)' > 
       <title>first name, last name</title>

    </path>   

    <path 
       d="M 170.46112,590.15502 L 170.14862,672.65541 L 171.71112,673.59291 L 174.67989,673.74916 L 176.08614,672.65541 L 178.58615,672.65541 L 178.74241,675.46792 L 185.46119,682.03045 L 185.92994,684.53046 L 189.2112,682.65545 L 189.83621,682.4992 L 190.14871,679.53044 L 191.55496,677.96793 L 192.64872,677.81168 L 194.52373,676.40542 L 197.49249,678.43668 L 198.1175,681.2492 L 199.9925,682.34295 L 201.08626,684.68671 L 204.83628,686.40547 L 208.11754,692.18675 L 210.7738,695.93676 L 212.96131,698.59303 L 214.36757,702.18679 L 219.21134,703.90555 L 224.21137,705.93681 L 225.14887,710.15558 L 225.61762,713.12434 L 224.68012,716.40561 L 222.96136,718.59312 L 221.39885,717.81187 L 219.9926,714.8431 L 217.33633,713.43685 L 215.61758,712.34309 L 214.83632,713.12434 L 216.24258,715.78061 L 216.39883,719.37437 L 215.30507,719.84312 L 213.43007,717.96812 L 211.39881,716.71811 L 211.86756,718.28062 L 213.11756,719.99938 L 212.33631,720.78063 C 212.33631,720.78063 211.55506,720.46813 211.08631,719.84312 C 210.61755,719.21812 209.05505,716.56186 209.05505,716.56186 L 208.11754,714.37435 C 208.11754,714.37435 207.80504,715.62436 207.18004,715.31185 C 206.55503,714.99935 205.93003,713.9056 205.93003,713.9056 L 207.64879,712.03059 L 206.24253,710.62433 L 206.24253,705.78056 L 205.46128,705.78056 L 204.68003,709.06182 L 203.58627,709.53058 L 202.64877,705.93681 L 202.02376,702.34304 L 201.24251,701.87429 L 201.55501,707.34307 L 201.55501,708.43682 L 200.14875,707.18682 L 196.71124,701.40554 L 194.67998,700.93679 L 194.05498,697.34302 L 192.49247,694.53051 L 190.92996,693.43675 L 190.92996,691.24924 L 192.96122,689.99924 L 192.49247,689.68674 L 189.99246,690.31174 L 186.71119,687.96798 L 184.21118,685.15546 L 179.52366,682.65545 L 175.61739,680.15544 L 176.8674,677.03043 L 176.8674,675.46792 L 175.14864,677.03043 L 172.33613,678.12418 L 168.74236,677.03043 L 163.27358,674.68667 L 157.96106,674.68667 L 157.33606,675.15542 L 151.08603,671.4054 L 149.05477,671.0929 L 146.39851,665.46787 L 142.96099,665.78037 L 139.52347,667.18663 L 139.99223,671.56165 L 141.08598,668.74914 L 142.02349,669.06164 L 140.61723,673.28041 L 143.74224,670.62415 L 144.36725,672.18665 L 140.61723,676.40542 L 139.36722,676.09292 L 138.89847,674.21791 L 137.64847,673.43666 L 136.39846,674.53042 L 133.7422,672.81166 L 130.77343,674.84292 L 129.05468,676.87418 L 125.77341,678.90544 L 121.24214,678.74918 L 120.77339,676.71793 L 124.36715,676.09292 L 124.36715,674.84292 L 122.17964,674.21791 L 123.11715,671.87415 L 125.30466,668.12414 L 125.30466,666.40538 L 125.46091,665.62412 L 129.67968,663.43661 L 130.61718,664.68662 L 133.27345,664.68662 L 132.02344,662.18661 L 128.42967,661.87411 L 123.5859,664.53037 L 121.24214,667.81163 L 119.52338,670.31165 L 118.42963,672.49916 L 114.36711,673.90541 L 111.39834,676.40542 L 111.08584,677.96793 L 113.27335,678.90544 L 114.05461,680.93669 L 111.39834,684.06171 L 105.14832,688.12423 L 97.648277,692.18675 L 95.617017,693.2805 L 90.460745,694.37426 L 85.304465,696.56177 L 87.023225,697.81177 L 85.616965,699.21803 L 85.148215,700.31178 L 82.491955,699.37428 L 79.366945,699.53053 L 78.585685,701.71804 L 77.648185,701.71804 L 77.960685,699.37428 L 74.523165,700.62429 L 71.710655,701.56179 L 68.42939,700.31178 L 65.616877,702.18679 L 62.491863,702.18679 L 60.460603,703.4368 L 58.898096,704.21805 L 56.866837,703.90555 L 54.366825,702.8118 L 52.179315,703.4368 L 51.241811,704.3743 L 49.679303,703.28055 L 49.679303,701.40554 L 52.648067,700.15553 L 58.741845,700.78054 L 62.960615,699.21803 L 64.991874,697.18677 L 67.804387,696.56177 L 69.523145,695.78051 L 72.179408,695.93676 L 73.741915,697.18677 L 74.679415,696.87427 L 76.866925,694.21801 L 79.835695,693.2805 L 83.116955,692.6555 L 84.366965,692.343 L 84.991965,692.81175 L 85.773225,692.81175 L 87.023225,689.21798 L 90.929495,687.81173 L 92.804505,684.21796 L 94.992017,679.84294 L 96.554527,678.43668 L 96.867027,675.93667 L 95.304517,677.18668 L 92.023245,677.81168 L 91.398245,675.46792 L 90.148245,675.15542 L 89.210735,676.09292 L 89.054485,678.90544 L 87.648225,678.74918 L 86.241975,673.12416 L 84.991965,674.37416 L 83.898215,673.90541 L 83.585715,672.0304 L 79.679445,672.18665 L 77.648185,673.28041 L 75.148175,672.96791 L 76.554425,671.56165 L 77.023175,669.06164 L 76.398175,667.18663 L 77.804435,666.24913 L 79.054435,666.09288 L 78.429435,664.37412 L 78.429435,660.15535 L 77.491935,659.21784 L 76.710675,660.6241 L 70.773151,660.6241 L 69.366895,659.37409 L 68.741892,655.62408 L 66.710632,652.18656 L 66.710632,651.24906 L 68.741892,650.4678 L 68.898142,648.43654 L 69.991897,647.34279 L 69.210644,646.87404 L 67.960638,647.34279 L 66.866883,644.68653 L 67.804387,639.84275 L 72.179408,636.71774 L 74.679415,635.15523 L 76.554425,631.56147 L 79.210695,630.31146 L 81.710705,631.40522 L 82.023205,633.74898 L 84.366965,633.43647 L 87.491975,631.09271 L 89.054485,631.71772 L 89.991985,632.34272 L 91.554495,632.34272 L 93.742007,631.09271 L 94.523267,626.87394 C 94.523267,626.87394 94.835767,624.06143 95.460767,623.59268 C 96.085767,623.12393 96.398267,622.65518 96.398267,622.65518 L 95.304517,620.78017 L 92.804505,621.56142 L 89.679485,622.34267 L 87.804475,621.87392 L 84.366965,620.15516 L 79.523195,619.99891 L 76.085675,616.40515 L 76.554425,612.65513 L 77.179435,610.31137 L 75.148175,608.59261 L 73.273163,604.99884 L 73.741915,604.21759 L 80.304445,603.74884 L 82.335705,603.74884 L 83.273205,604.68634 L 83.898215,604.68634 L 83.741965,603.12383 L 87.491975,602.49883 L 89.991985,602.81133 L 91.398245,603.90509 L 89.991985,605.93635 L 89.523235,607.3426 L 92.179505,608.90511 L 97.023277,610.62387 L 98.742037,609.68637 L 96.554527,605.4676 L 95.617017,602.34258 L 96.554527,601.56133 L 93.273257,599.68632 L 92.804505,598.59256 L 93.273257,597.03006 L 92.492005,593.28004 L 89.679485,588.74877 L 87.335725,584.68625 L 90.148245,582.81124 L 93.273257,582.81124 L 94.992017,583.43624 L 99.054537,583.27999 L 102.6483,579.84248 L 103.74206,576.87371 L 107.33583,574.52995 L 108.89833,575.46746 L 111.55459,574.84245 L 115.14836,572.81119 L 116.24212,572.65494 L 117.17962,573.4362 L 121.55464,573.27995 L 124.2109,570.31118 L 125.30466,570.31118 L 128.74217,572.65494 L 130.61718,574.6862 L 130.14843,575.77996 L 130.77343,576.87371 L 132.33594,575.31121 L 136.08596,575.62371 L 136.39846,579.21747 L 138.27347,580.62373 L 145.1485,581.24873 L 151.24228,585.31125 L 152.64853,584.37375 L 157.64856,586.87376 L 159.67982,586.24876 L 161.55483,585.4675 L 166.24235,587.34251 L 170.46112,590.15502 z M 59.210598,618.1239 L 61.241857,623.28018 L 61.085606,624.21768 L 58.273093,623.90518 L 56.554335,619.99891 L 54.835577,618.59266 L 52.491816,618.59266 L 52.335566,616.09264 L 54.054324,613.74888 L 55.148079,616.09264 L 56.554335,617.4989 L 59.210598,618.1239 z M 56.710586,650.4678 L 60.304353,651.24906 L 63.898119,652.18656 L 64.679373,653.12407 L 63.116866,656.71783 L 60.148102,656.56158 L 56.866837,653.12407 L 56.710586,650.4678 z M 36.710493,636.87399 L 37.804249,639.374 L 38.898004,640.93651 L 37.804249,641.71776 L 35.772989,638.749 L 35.772989,636.87399 L 36.710493,636.87399 z M 23.429182,707.49932 L 26.710447,705.31181 L 29.991712,704.3743 L 32.491724,704.6868 L 32.960476,706.24931 L 34.835485,706.71806 L 36.710493,704.84306 L 36.397992,703.28055 L 39.054254,702.65555 L 41.866767,705.15556 L 40.773012,706.87431 L 36.554243,707.96807 L 33.89798,707.49932 L 30.304214,706.40556 L 26.085444,707.81182 L 24.522937,708.12432 L 23.429182,707.49932 z M 70.773151,703.1243 L 72.335658,704.99931 L 74.366915,703.4368 L 72.960661,702.18679 L 70.773151,703.1243 z M 73.585664,706.09306 L 74.679415,703.90555 L 76.710675,704.21805 L 75.929425,706.09306 L 73.585664,706.09306 z M 96.398267,704.21805 L 97.804527,705.93681 L 98.742037,704.84306 L 97.960777,702.96805 L 96.398267,704.21805 z M 104.83581,692.18675 L 105.92957,697.81177 L 108.74208,698.59303 L 113.58585,695.78051 L 117.80462,693.2805 L 116.24212,690.93674 L 116.71087,688.59298 L 114.67961,689.84299 L 111.8671,689.06173 L 113.4296,687.96798 L 115.30461,688.74923 L 119.05463,687.03047 L 119.52338,685.62422 L 117.17962,684.84296 L 117.96087,682.96795 L 115.30461,684.84296 L 110.77334,688.28048 L 106.08582,691.09299 L 104.83581,692.18675 z M 145.7735,672.96791 L 148.11726,671.56165 L 147.17976,669.84289 L 145.461,670.7804 L 145.7735,672.96791 z"
       id="AK"
       style="fill:#f2d0ff" onmousemove=' GetTrueCoords(evt); ShowTooltip(evt, true)' onmouseout='ShowTooltip(evt, false)' > 
    <title>this sis ak</title>
    </path>
```

Comment: What is the source of this text? Is it in a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little bit unclear how you intend to retrieve and store that data into a single VBA string, but if you are going to try to copy and paste the contents of the text you posted and have available in-memory as a string in VBA, here's how you might approach it.

The biggest thing to remember is to escape your double quotes and line-breaks.  I replaced all `"` with `" & chr(34) & "` and added a `vbCrLf` to the end of the line.  The first few lines of your file might look like this when consumed in VBA:

```
Public Sub TestString()
    Dim str As String

    str = ""

    str = str & "<svg  " & vbCrLf
    str = str & "   xmlns:dc=" & Chr(34) & "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" & Chr(34) & " " & vbCrLf
    str = str & "   xmlns:cc=" & Chr(34) & "http://creativecommons.org/ns#" & Chr(34) & " " & vbCrLf
    str = str & "   xmlns:rdf=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" & Chr(34) & " " & vbCrLf
    str = str & "   xmlns:svg=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" & Chr(34) & " " & vbCrLf
    str = str & "   xmlns=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" & Chr(34) & " " & vbCrLf
    str = str & "   xmlns:sodipodi=" & Chr(34) & "http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" & Chr(34) & " " & vbCrLf
    str = str & "   xmlns:inkscape=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" & Chr(34) & " " & vbCrLf
    str = str & "   version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & " " & vbCrLf
    str = str & "   width=" & Chr(34) & "958.69" & Chr(34) & " " & vbCrLf
    str = str & "   height=" & Chr(34) & "592.78998" & Chr(34) & " " & vbCrLf
    str = str & "   id=" & Chr(34) & "svg2275" & Chr(34) & " " & vbCrLf
    str = str & "   sodipodi:version=" & Chr(34) & "0.32" & Chr(34) & " " & vbCrLf


    Debug.Print str

End Sub
```

To make it easier to generate those lines of `str = str ...` code, I pasted your code into Excel and used the following Excel formula which allowed me to simply paste the resulting Excel-calculated text right into the VBA editor:

```
="str = str & " & CHAR(34) & SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(34),CHAR(34) & " & chr(34) & " & CHAR(34)) & CHAR(34) & " & vbCrLf"
```

I tried pasting everything you had into VBA, but some of the lines of your original text were way too long (the lines with numbers) and took up multiple rows in the VBA editor.  That can be fixed fairly simply by breaking up those lines into multiple `str = str & ...` lines, except without the `vbCrLf` at the end.

Comment: By the way, double quotes in VB/VBA can be escaped with another double-quote, so instead of `"height=" & Chr(34) & "592.78998" & Chr(34)` you can simply write `"height=""592.78998"""`.

Comment: @0xA3 very good point. I guess I use `chr(34)` since I learned to do that before I learned about escaping the double quotes.  I also get confused by looking at lots of pairs of double quotes :-).

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is to replace characters.

Just for simplification, supose you must store one string containing this:

```
  height="595.63739"
```

... then, you could substitute the double quotes by an alternate character, ending with someghing like this:

```
  height=#595.63739#
```

... and the code for the whole thing:

```
str = "height=#595.63739#"
str = Replace(str, "#", Chr(34))
```

There, your string is easier to manage, cause it doesn't need the extra concatenations.

Cons:

- You may end messing with a wrong char
  alternative - in the exemple, supose
  you have, actually, some "#" in your
  string.
- I'm not sure about
  performance issues.